# On topic : Raspberry Pi accessories?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have found a few old Kickstart projects, such as [this](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/geekroo/pipeye-an-advanced-battery-hat-to-power-your-raspb/posts/1323876), which consist of a case (not on-topic), containing a Real Time Clock and battery power for the Pi.

Some have a few extra features, such as a display, or solar power panel, etc.

Question: if I detail my requirements, would a question asking for such a thing be on topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that sounds on topic to me:

> Hardware is any primarily electronic item that can perform more than one task, designed to interface with, connect to, or be, a primary computing platform in day-to-day operation.
>
> A primary computing platform is any primarily electronic item that can perform meaningful tasks on its own with minimal external support, and designed to be operated by a user, consumer or professional.

This sounds a lot like a component in a desktop or laptop. It's a component designed to interface with the primary computing platform.